# How to run Multi Profile in WSO2 APIM 3.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to run multi profile in WSO2 APIM.How i can do that ? I would like to run profile-gateway,traffic manager and publisher in profile.

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/

Comment: As per example in document we can run one product profile to optimize,How can we ran the mutiple profiles ?

Comment: you can’t do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the docs to get an idea about wso2 APIM product profiles. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/next/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/#product-profiles